# conditional rendering with two values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I want to render my component if id equal to 15 or 12. 
Here is below how I'm doing , but it doesnt work. It renders if leave only one id, but I need check for two statements

```
   {query_estate_id === 15  || 12   && <span
    onClick={() => this.toggleFlatsView(2)}
    className={cn({ active: flatsView === 2 })}
    >
      3d 
   </span>}
```

Comment: `query_estate_id === 15  || query_estate_id  === 12`

Comment: There has to be a good dupetarget for this...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder trying to find it but it's super annoying to search for it...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder there it is! Well done! I keep forgetting the exact magical phrase to conjure it forth. I was trying "or many" and "one of many" and few variations. It's *list*. I just have to get a bunch of links in a document because there are few good dupes that are a pain to search for if you don't remember the exact title.

Comment: { [15,12].includes(query_estate_id) &&  <span...

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare against two values like that in JavaScript. Instead, repeat the variable name:

```
{(query_estate_id === 15 || query_estate_id === 12) && ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    {query_estate_id === 15 || query_estate_id === 12 ? (
      <span
        onClick={() => this.toggleFlatsView(2)}
        className={cn({ active: flatsView === 2 })}
      >
        3d
      </span>
    ) : null}
```